# how to display a multiselect customer attribute on frontend

Tags: frontend, multiselect-attribute, customer-attribute

I added a multiselect attribute to customers. It works fine in the backend.
Now I would show it in fronted customer edit template, so that customer can display or change options.

Is there any magento function to show it or I need to create it?

Comment: Magento has no option for your problem.Use this extension for multiselect options.http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: thanks, nice jquery plugin, but how to get chosen options by the user?

Comment: This chosen allows new values add to select options.so new values added to that attribute .

Comment: @AntonioPedicini were you able to solve this problem? If so, how?

Comment: @ManikandanArunachalam why not add your comment as answer

Comment: @ManikandanArunachalam aaaaand upvoted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento has no option for your problem.Use this extension for multiselect options.[Chosen Select](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen)

This chosen allows new values add to select options.so new values added to that attribute.